# Can I use ActionMailer when using a 3rd party library to send emails via http?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I am using a 3rd party library that sends emails using a HTTP based API.

Is it still possible for me to use ActionMailer to construct the emails and then somehow use ActionMailer to generate the resulting HTML/text for the email which I could then pass to my http email lib to send?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. In fact, this is standard practice. You don't need to do anything special, just configure ActionMailer to use the 3rd party of your choice. Here's an example from my `production.rb` file, using Mailgun:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # other config stuff goes here...

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'your_domain.com' }
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    authentication: :plain,
    address: 'smtp.mailgun.org',
    port: 587,
    domain: Rails.application.secrets[:mailgun_domain],
    user_name: Rails.application.secrets[:mailgun_username],
    password: Rails.application.secrets[:mailgun_password]
  }
end
```

Then in your `Rails.application.secrets` file, you put the info specific to your account.

Comment: I am using mailgun also, but I am using the http api not the smtp method.  that is why I asked if I can still leverage actionmailer.

Comment: In that case https://github.com/jorgemanrubia/mailgun_rails looks like it would do the trick.